# Multiple GET requests using JQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Very new to JQuery AJAX here.   I have been looking around for a answer for awhile on this and can't find an answer.

I have a form that users would fill out.  Once filled click on submit.  This starts an ajax call to an asp page and basically just displays the information that was entered and fades out the user form.  A confirm button below that takes the user to another .asp page that puts it into a database and gives them a ticket number.

My issue is that on the second call ( page that does the input ) , I notice in firebug that the get is happening twice.  If I try the asp page alone it is only doing the input once so it's not my sql code.  If I switch the second .asp page with the first it works fine.

Here is my jquery.  I appreciate any comments.  Thanks

```
 $('#submit').click(function (event){
event.preventDefault(); // DECLARE EVENT IN THE CLICK FUNCTION

//Get the data from all the fields 
var posting = 'no';
var firstname = $('input[name="firstname"]');
var lastname = $('input[name="lastname"]');
var phone = $('input[name="phone"]');
var email = $('input[name="email"]');
var family_size = $('select[name="family_size"]');
var date_3 = $("#date3");
var date_4 = $("#date4");
var book_option = $('input[name=book_option]:radio:checked');
var payment_type = $('input[name=payment_type]:radio:checked');
var comments = $('textarea[name="comments"]');

if (firstname.val()=='') { 
       firstname.addClass('fn_error');
       firstname.focus(); 
       return false;       
} else 
    firstname.removeClass('fn_error');

if (lastname.val()=='') {
       lastname.addClass('ln_error');
       lastname.focus();
       return false;       
} else 
    lastname.removeClass('ln_error');

if (phone.val()=='') {
       phone.addClass('fn_error');
       phone.focus();
       return false;       
} else 
    phone.removeClass('fn_error');

if (email.val()=='') { 
      email.addClass('ln_error');
      email.focus();
      return false;        
} else 
    email.removeClass('ln_error');

// TEST FOR VALID EMAIL
var email_pattern=new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$");
var email_result = email_pattern.test(email.val());
if( email_result == true ) {
    email.removeClass('fn_error');
}else{
    email.addClass('fn_error');
    email.focus();
    return false;
}

// TEST FOR VALID PHONE NUMBER
var phone_pattern= 
    new RegExp("^(\\(?\\d\\d\\d\\)?)?( |-|\\.)?\\d\\d\\d( |-|\\.)?\\d{4,4}(( |-|\\.)?[ext\\.]+ ?\\d+)?$");
var phone_result = phone_pattern.test(phone.val());
if( phone_result == true ) {
    phone.removeClass('fn_error');
}else{
    phone.addClass('fn_error');
    phone.focus();
    return false;
}

var dataString= 'firstname=' + firstname.val() + '&lastname=' + lastname.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&family_size=' + family_size.val() + '&date3=' + date_3.val() + '&date4=' + date_4.val() + '&book_option=' + book_option.val() + '&payment_type=' + payment_type.val() + '&comments=' + comments.val() + '&posting=' + posting;

//alert(dataString);  
$('#ticketform').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#testdiv').load('../resources/confirm_ticket.asp', dataString, function() {
        $('#generateform').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#submit').unbind('click');
    });

}); // LOAD CLOSE
}); // SUBMIT CLICK FUNCTION CLOSE

$('#gen').click(function (event){
event.preventDefault(); // DECLARE EVENT IN THE CLICK FUNCTION

var firstname = $('input[name="firstname"]');
var lastname = $('input[name="lastname"]');
var phone = $('input[name="phone"]');
var email = $('input[name="email"]');
var family_size = $('select[name="family_size"]');
var date_3 = $("#date3");
var date_4 = $("#date4");
var book_option = $('input[name=book_option]:radio:checked');
var payment_type = $('input[name=payment_type]:radio:checked');
var comments = $('textarea[name="comments"]');

var dataString= 'firstname=' + firstname.val() + '&lastname=' + lastname.val() + '&phone=' + phone.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&family_size=' + family_size.val() + '&date3=' + date_3.val() + '&date4=' + date_4.val() + '&book_option=' + book_option.val() + '&payment_type=' + payment_type.val() + '&comments=' + comments.val();

alert(dataString);  
$('#testdiv, #generateform').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#message').load('../resources/generate_ticket.asp', function() {
        $('#message').fadeIn('slow'); 
    });

}); // LOAD CLOSE

   }); // SUBMIT2 CLICK FUNCTION CLOSE
```

Comment: you can start by actually minimizing the code only to the related sections

Comment: Id suggest doing: var postData $('#yourFormID").serialize(); and perhaps the jQuery form validator http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 1):

First off, a better way to verify if a field is filled in is to use jQuery `$.trim()`, it will trim all white space in the beginning and end so if someone enters a bunch of spaces, it will return false still. This is how you would do it:

```
if ($.trim(firstname.val())) { 
       firstname.addClass('fn_error');
       firstname.focus(); 
       return false;       
}
```

This is a much better way to verify if it is empty, but *an even better idea is to use the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), in which you can simple put `class="required"`, `class="required email"`, etc. for each rule (they can also be defined in the javascript if you prefer).*

Also, I see that you keep using `.load`. Did you know a thing called [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) exists? It is a little more powerful way to send a get request and you don't have to load it into an element to make it work (there's also [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)). I used to use `.load` myself all the time a while back until I discovered `$.get` and `$.post`. This is an example with your code:

```
$.get('../resources/confirm_ticket.asp', dataString, function(data) { // data is what is returned from the request (html, etc.)
        $('#generateform').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#submit').unbind('click');
});
```

**Anyway, now to your question.**

I don't see any problems of why it would be doing that, but it could be a bug with the browser or something (usually not but this happened to me before too and I never found out how to fix it). Have you tried it in other browsers like Google Chrome or Safari?

Comment: Thanks for the input :)  Yeah, I've tried it with Google Chrome, Firefox and IE.  All do the same thing.  I will try using .get instead to see if that works.

Comment: It's definitely something with the Jquery.  I've tried different asp pages and they all do the load twice on the second click.

Comment: The actual submit button needs to be on the initial page before the ajax call right?  I've tried to load it from the asp page that it calls but it just ends up doing the default form post method.

Comment: @krystofurr If you are dynamically loading the button, you have to use `$('#submit').live('click',function() {` so it will always bind the event to the element even if it's loaded after it is binded. Also, maybe you should be triggering it when the form actually submits, rather than triggering it when the button is clicked, because you know when you press enter on a form element, it submits. So if you use something like: `$('#form_id').submit(function() {` maybe that could fix it? I'm not sure, but it's worth a try :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from a forum today.  Can't remember where but the answer is....

```
$('#testdiv, #generateform').fadeOut('slow', function() {
$('#message').load('../resources/generate_ticket.asp', function() {
    $('#message').fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

I have 2 selectors in the fadeOut.  It was calling the load function twice for each selector.  Changed it and now I'm only getting the one GET request.  Thanks for the help though all! :) Happy Coding!